# Prevent a list based on an input's focus to disappear when clicking into it

Tags: javascript, html, focus, blur

I have been tried to write a custom  inspired element with an input field where the user can write and a list that appears and disappears based on input's focus.

```js
const unitsList = {lenght:{fm:"femtometers (fm)",pm:"picometers (pm)",nm:"nanometers (nm)",um:"micrometers (μm)",mm:"millimiters (mm)",cm:"centimiters (cm)",dm:"decimeters (dm)",m:"meters (m)",dam:"decameters (dam)",hm:"hectometers (hm)",km:"kilometers (km)",in:"inchs (in)",ft:"foots (ft)",yd:"yards (yd)",mi:"miles (mi)"}}

let groups = ['lenght', ]

function $$(id) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(id);
}

function s$(id) {
  return document.querySelector(id);
}

$$('ul').forEach(selector => {
  for (group of groups) {
    for (unit in unitsList[group]) {
      selector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li onclick="console.log('${unit}')">${unitsList[group][unit]}</li>`);
    }
  }
})

$$('.customSelectorInput').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    $$('ul').forEach(() => {
      s$(`#${input.parentNode.id} > ul`).hidden = false;
    })
  })
})

$$('.customSelectorInput').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    $$('ul').forEach(() => {
      s$(`#${input.parentNode.id} > ul`).hidden = true;
    })
  })
})
```

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">

  <div id="inSelector">
    <input type="text" class="customSelectorInput">

    <ul hidden id="inList"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the input loses focus when the user clicks on the list and that happens before the onclick is able to work.
I have tried several methods, including but not limited to `event.stopPropagation()`, disabling `useCapture` or refocusing the input on a list's click event handler but nothing seems to work.

I'd really appreciate someone's help.

Comment: can you please create working model of this code?

Comment: Sure, here you are https://jsfiddle.net/yb0qxsLm/7/

Comment: I don't have the ability to test this, but I think that the CSS `.inputContainer:focus-within ul[hidden] {display: block;}` *may* help.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I tried and it seems like it doesn't work either @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
let isListClicked = false;

onListClick() {
  isListClicked = true;
  //do something on click item 
};

onBlur() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!selectClick) {
      //do something on blur
    };
    selectClick = false;
  }, 250);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for typescript. This is like approach